# How to set addon store icon for Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm creating a Firefox **Web Extension** (not the old style addon). My application has a `manifest.json` file, and I've set the icons:

```
  "icons": {
    "16": "data/icons/icon-16.png",
    "24": "data/icons/icon-24.png",
    "48": "data/icons/icon-48.png",
    "64": "data/icons/icon-64.png",
    "96": "data/icons/icon-96.png",
    "128": "data/icons/icon-128.png"
  },
```

However, the icon still shows the default plugin icon on the addons page:

[image]

The icon shows correctly in the firefox addon manager though. I've also tried putting an `icon.png` and `icon@2x.png` file in the root directory of my addon, but no luck.

I have an old style addon that shows right above my new addon that does have a custom icon, so I assume it's possible. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Could you try to load temp/unpacked add-on in Firefox and see if the icon can show?

Comment: Your addon is unlisted? If it is, does setting an icon on AMO affect anything?

Answer (score 4):

On the manage addon info page:

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/YOUR_ADDON_SLUG_GOES_HERE/edit
```

There is a section "Images". Click "Edit", then you will get an upload form. You have to set the icon there:

[image]

Comment: No such image section is there. I've checked just now. I see only `Basic Information`, `Add-on Details` and `Technical Details`

Comment: @user5858 please give me a link to your addon, I will see what's going on.

Comment: http://www.telanganasandautofill.com/sites/default/files/telangana_sand_online_autofill-3.1-an-fx.xpi

Comment: @user5858 - it seems your addon is unlisted. Please link me to your addon page on addons.mozilla.org

Comment: all my firefox addons are unlisted except for one.

Comment: @user5858 I'm not sure if you can set the icon on unlisted addons on AMO. Does it have any affect anywhereE

Comment: @user5858 does setting the icon on AMO affect unlisted addons?

Comment: i don't find any option in the AMO to change icon for my unlisted addon

Comment: @user5858 I think this is because it has no effect. Are you seeing the generic icon somewhere and want to change that?

Answer (score 0):

On the manifest.json, you should add more icons like:

```
"icons": {
    "16": "icons/afc16.png",
    "19": "icons/afc19.png",
    "24": "icons/afc24.png",
    "32": "icons/afc32.png",
    "38": "icons/afc38.png",
    "48": "icons/afc48.png",
    "64": "icons/afc64.png",
    "96": "icons/afc96.png",
    "128": "icons/afc128.png"
},
"browser_action": {
"browser_style": true,
"default_icon": {
  "16": "icons/afc16.png",
  "32": "icons/afc32.png",
  "64": "icons/afc64.png"
}
},
```